# Define operator in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am doing a lot of prolog exercises to improve my logic skills. But i'm stuck with the request of an exercise.

What i have to do is to define an operator **i** , in a way that: if the user inputs a complex number with this syntax , via the prompt ( so i use the read(X) operator)

```
(4+ i 7) - (2+ i 3).
```

i get as result

```
2+ i 4
```

I've understood how to define an operator in Prolog,i've studied the **op** operator but i dont know how make that subtraction operation really happen

Comment: Post the code for your attempts

Comment: I've just defined the op :-op(600,xfx,i). I dont know how to implement the substration operator using this i operator

Comment: This may be of inspiration: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2

Comment: Ok, that defines the name, type and precedence foryour operation. Did you define a i predicate that actually does the work?

Comment: The - operator is already present, i dont know how to override it

Comment: You don't need to override the operator. All an operator does in Prolog is allow you to construct terms. It's up to you to imbue them with meaning by implementing some kind of evaluator that takes apart those terms and does something with them.

Comment: Let me elaborate for a second. All `op/3` does in Prolog is notify the parser that a certain atom is to be parsed infix, or whatever. Prolog operators are not magically evaluated in a manner different from everything else in Prolog. Even the arithmetic operators are not evaluated in the traditional sense, `is/2` is a relation like any other, between an arithmetic term and a numeric value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that `xfx` defines a binary operator, and you want a unary operator, so you need a declaration like this:

```
:- op(600, xf, i).
```

Your second problem is that, there is no circumstance in which entering arithmetic expressions at the Prolog query prompt will result in anything like reduction happening automatically. See:

```
?- 3 + 4 * 7.
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (+)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

?- X = 3 + 4 * 7.
X = 3+4*7.
```

In order to cause arithmetic to be evaluated, you have to use the `is/2` operator:

```
?- X is 3 + 4 * 7.
X = 31.
```

Try and think of `is/2` as just another predicate, relating a numeric value with an expression. There is no way in ISO Prolog to modify the behavior of `is/2`, so you'll have to make an evaluation predicate of your own and use that:

```
eval((A + B i) + (C + D i), E + F i) :- 
    E is A + C, 
    F is B + D.
```

Once you have that, you can use it the usual way:

```
?- eval((3 + 4 i) + (7 + 8 i), X).
X = 10+12 i.
```

As you can see, this is probably going to get tedious, but it will work. If you want to gin up more comprehensive support for complex numbers by hand, you should consider making a metainterpreter.

Comment: That eval, shouldn't that be recursive?

Comment: @false to do it right, yes, but I am worried about confusing the OP further as it is

Comment: Btw, you can even write `3+4i`